# How to build a deep learning text classifier using convolutional neural networks (python)

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, text-classification

What are the steps I would need to take to build a deep learning text classifier, more specifically a text classifier that identifies an author (authorship attribution) in a set of unlabeled texts? The model I am looking at using is word-word CNN (convolutional neural network) which has proven to be very successful in things such as text classification. I am looking to build this model in python.

I am new to deep learning so any resources and information is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An End to End Example to demonstrate how to use `Convolutional Neural Networks` for `Text Classification` using `Tensorflow.Keras` is shown below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
max_features = 10000
max_len = 500
print('Loading data...')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
print(len(x_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(x_test), 'test sequences')
print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=max_len)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=max_len)
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape:', x_test.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=max_len))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 7, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(5))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 7, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
loss='binary_crossentropy',
metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=10,batch_size=128,validation_split=0.2)
```

For more information please refer **Section 6.4 Sequence processing with convnets** in the book, **`Deep Learning Using Python`** written by Francois Chollet, the Father of Keras.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!